# Collect the basic instace details from puppetdb like the hostname and IP based on some facts value

Tags: puppet

How can i develop  a script which automatically runs and fetches the details from puppetdb ? I am a newbie to puppet .Basically I would like to collect the  inventory from puppetdb based on factor values like "web server" ,"app server" etc. I use opensource puppet.

Comment: For your use-case, and maybe just getting your feet wet, the top answer isn't wrong, but running something like [Puppetboard](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppetboard) might be an alternative or a complementary strategy. It's easy to setup, and offers a pretty decent GUI. Also, I find the [PQL](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/5.1/api/query/v4/pql.html) to be a great deal more readable than the old-style api queries... sandbox directly from a puppet server.

Comment: I second @mburling running Puppetboard would make your life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

querying puppetdb is as easy as running curl.

For example, if you have a fact named $role and some nodes have the role "web server" you can get an inventory dump of all nodes with that role running:

```
 curl -G -H  "Accept: application/json" 'http://localhost:8080/pdb/query/v4/inventory' --data-urlencode 'query=["=",["fact","role"], "web server"]' |jq '.'
```

Now, maybe you only want to know the hostname of servers and send each inventory to another application, that would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Iterate over nodes if $role 'web server'
curl -s -G -H  "Accept: application/json" 'http://localhost:8080/pdb/query/v4/nodes' --data-urlencode 'query=["=",["fact","role"], "web server"]' | jq -r '.[]|[ .certname ]| @tsv' |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r host; do
  echo "Do something with $host"
  # Save one dump per host
  curl -s -G -H  "Accept: application/json" 'http://localhost:8080/pdb/query/v4/inventory' --data-urlencode 'query=["=","certname","'${host}'"]' > "node-${host}.inventory.log"
done
```

This are very basic examples, their api is very powerful and very simple to use, you can query anything (facts, resources, catalogs, inventories) and doing even complex queries like speaking to a MySQL server, check their tutorial here:  https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/5.1/api/query/tutorial.html .